# Silhouette not working in r

Tags: r

Running R 3.5.1 in R Studio.

I’ve edited `pam.res$clustering` to manually change the clusters.

Used `silhouette()` to try to observe the silhouette info for the edited clustering:

```
mahal<-D2.dist(data, cov.wt(data)$cov)
newsil<-silhouette(pam.res$clustering, mahal)
```

And all I get from `summary(newsil)` is

```
   Mode   NA’s
logical      1
```

I can’t reference within `newsil`, as it’s an atomic vector, which it shouldn’t be.

Can’t figure out what’s gone wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example that creates the problems that you're seeing? Without access to your data, we have no way of knowing what the underlying issue may be.

Comment: Thanks! That ended up being enough for me to figure it out! Once I ran it with a dataset that I could load from r that was a lot more managable than mine, running through the procedure I saw the error was in how I edited the clustering, which I have fixed now.